# You know this Ben Grimm/Thing quote?

Tags: marvel, comics, quotes, fantastic-four, the-thing

I watched a Marvel [AMV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anime_music_video) video on YouTube.

In one of the Marvel comics, the Thing teams up with a few superheroes to take down a villain. They were maybe the Hulk, Gladiator, and the Silver Surfer. The bad guy exploited the heroes' weaknesses and paralyzed them in the ground.

He told them his evil plan to blow up the planet or something to kill a bunch of people.
Then, the Thing gets up and says that he is not the same as the others. He maybe is not that strong or doesn't have fancy abilities like them, but he doesn't have a weakness. He always was a type who never gives up, never knows when to stay down, and he always just needed a reason to fight.
Now, he gave him 3 billion reasons!

I hope somebody knows the specific quote or the Marvel comic book!

Comment: A link to the AMV would be helpful

Comment: Obviusly, if I remember that amv video I dont ask this question!

Comment: Not that obvious, you might have just forgotten to include the link :) some more questions then. About the comic issue: when do you think it would have been published? 60s-ish look, or a newer, "fancier" look? About the video: how long was it? Did it feature other Marvel characters/plots/media such as cartoons, etc? What song was used, or if you don't remember, what genre? Does typing `AMV`or `marvel youtube` in your browser history give you any video you know isn't it?

Comment: If the comic assumed 3 billion people on Earth, then it was likely from 1970 or thereabout. Thing is obviously the hero here and they seem to push the "Ben Grimm never gives up" narrative hard. This makes it sound like it might have been from an early Marvel Two-In-One comic. In that series they had The Thing team up with other heroes regularly, he usually was the hero in the end, and they practically invented the concept of Thing as unwilling to surrender, ever. I recommend you begin the search there.

Comment: My first thought was the Marvel Two-in-One Annual against [Champion of the Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champion_of_the_Universe) because that's one of the quintessential "Ben doesn't give up" issues, but he doesn't target weaknesses.